# how to pass an error message back before an exception is thrown

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch

i have the following  code that gets an error message.i want to pass it into a string before an exception is thrown,this is my code

```
ValidateError(authDeserialized, "Succeed", "error", "failed"); //the validateError is a function as indicated below
Model.Response= authResponse.Content;

 protected static void ValidateError(dynamic response, string validStatus,string categoryMatch, string message)
        {  
            if (response.result.status != validStatus)
            {
                try
                {
                    var category = response.result.category;
                    if (category == categoryMatch)
                          message=ErrorCodes.MessageFor(code,description);
      //so i get the message back fine here but now how do i pass it back to this line   Model.Response= authResponse.Content; so that it can get saved?
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
                throw new Exception(message ?? "Request was not successfull");
            }
        }
```

Comment: is `authResponse` accessible inside `ValidateError` message? if yes then assign it when you are building that error message or in `catch` block. Do you want to assign error message to `authResponse` and also you want to throw an error is that correct?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar the authResponse is not accessible inside the ValidateError. yes i want to assign the error message to autResponse.content

Comment: Hi @PrasadTelkikar it doesn't return the message it just throws the exception without returning the message

Comment: it will not return message, but updated error message will get stored in message variable. Did you read documentation of `out` parameter and checked my answer. I suggest you to read documentation first change your code as per my answer and then debug. **Answer will not return any message but it will update error message which is stored in `failureMessage`**

Answer (score 0):

As you are already sending `message` to the `ValidateError()` method, pass that parameter as a [`out` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier), it will update value of `message` if you assign new value to it then it will update message and will be accessible to outside environment.

```
string failureMessage = "failed";
ValidateError(authDeserialized, "Succeed", "error", out failureMessage);
                                                  //^^^ This is what you have to change
//Now you can assign failureMessage to any other value
Model.Response= authResponse.Content;

protected static void ValidateError(dynamic response, string validStatus,string categoryMatch, out string message)
{                                                                                            //^^^ This is what you have to change
      if (response.result.status != validStatus)
      {
          try
          {
               var category = response.result.category;
               if (category == categoryMatch)
                   message=ErrorCodes.MessageFor(code,description);    //so i get the message back fine here but now how do i pass it back to this line   Model.Response= authResponse.Content; so that it can get saved?
          }
          catch (Exception) { }
          throw new Exception(message ?? "Request was not successfull");
      }
}
```

In this way you can assign value to failure message before throwing an error.

> [Try out online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KSwKcu)